# Amazon EC2 Instance - Where to add the credentials file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 Instance. On my Instance I want to run a python program. The program tries to access other amazon services. On my Mac the program worked fine, because the credentials file is in the folder "~/.aws/credentials". But I don't know where on my amazon EC2 instance the library "~" is. So where do I have to put my credentials? Hope you can help me.

Comment: to reiterate what @mark-b said, **don't use hardcoded credentials on an ec2 instance**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~` is a shortcut for your home directory. Just go into that directory using the command `cd ~`. This is the directory you will always start in when you SSH into your server.

Alternatively you could install the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and run `aws configure`. If you are using Amazon Linux then the AWS CLI tool is already installed.

Also, storing credentials on your EC2 instance is not the preferred method. You should look into using [EC2 instance profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html).